# What is the expected life span of vascular stents?

Tags: medications, blood-circulation, cardiovascular-disease, venous-system, stents

What is the expected life span of vascular stents?

For example: Universal (coronary/venous) stent WALLSTENT-UNI Boston Scientific, metal: nitinol = titanium + nickel.

1. How many pulsating contractions can it withstand? Is it more than `80 heart_rate * 60 min * 24 hours * 365 days * 10 years ~= 400 millions pulsations`?

   - In artery
   - In vein (for extravasal compression - aortovenous conflict - arterial pulsation affects stent in vein)
2. How many years can (the non-grown into a vessel) areas of the stent be in the patient’s blood flow until these stent areas are destroyed?

https://fda.report/MAUDE/MDR/8301298

Are there any data, whether from the manufacturer or obtained statistically about stent life span?

Comment: This is a question I both love and hate - and I mean that with full respect for the intent. :) This just isn't a question asked in the field: stent fracture is a big deal but lifetime of stents is asked based on restenosis and a wide variety of other factors. It's not related to "in flow" strut degradation

Comment: @BryanKrause That's exactly what I thought about this question. Thank you for expressing it so well. You could make a great answer out of this.

Comment: @BryanKrause This is the question: why does everyone bypass the issue of stent fragmentation? Especially when it comes to venous stents, where with a ~95% probability there will be no restenosis in the next 40 years. Does it mean that the manufacturer guarantee that ~99% of venous/universal stents can withstand a pulsating effect for 40 years with aorto-venous conflicts (pulsation from an artery is transmitted to a stent in a vein, and forty years of blood flow)?